# Java/android Interface method automatic parameter passing concept

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

After hr and half of frustration, I can't seem to put my problem into words, so it can't be Googled, so I turn to stackoverflow for a simple explanation of "the interface method parameters automatic value passing concept". I can't quite get the words to explain the issue, but i will try my best.

I know how `java interface` works, but i don't understand the way its being used, when it comes to implementing `listener` or other `classes` in android, where a certain value is pass to you via the `override` method param. For example when you implement a `addTextChangedListener` on a `Edittext` you have to `override` all these methods(`onTextChanged`,`beforeTextChanged`, `afterTextChanged`). And in the parameter of these methods, the value is automatically passed to you, where is that param value coming from. Normally when you `override` an `interface` method or any other method you pass in the value in the params, but here its somehow automatically done for you. The value is automatically pass into the param of the `overridden` method you just retrieve it via declaring a var and setting it equal to the param value. A `hello world` equivalent example on this concept will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I can totally get where you're coming from. For me I was always wondering where these values are coming from.  I think just looking at more and more sample code and literally reading it over and over helped me understand.

Comment: the values are not passed automatically. they are passed by the android classes. In the case of the EditText, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.sendOnTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: typically sendOnTextChanged is called by http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#3816 in TextView.setText

Comment: You are a bit confused about what an interface is. It is only a contract, the classes you pass in as listeners adhere to that contract, because they have a method/s with the signature defined by the interface. Then some class will explicitly call your listener.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a interface with some method, that excepts something or not.
2. Create a instance of this interface, that overrides the method, and does something.
3. Create a method that needs this interface as a parameter.
4. Call this method with the parameter that you created in 2. point, and another parameter if your interface needs a parameter.

`public interface RequestInterface { public void execute(String val);
    }`

```
RequestInterface helloWorld= new RequestInterface () {

    @Override
    public void execute(String val) {
        Log.i("tag", val);
    }
};
private void methodThatWantsToCallAInterface(String valueToPutInside,RequestInterface command){
    command.execute(valueToPutInside);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     methodThatWantsToCallAInterface("Some string",helloWorld); //logs "Some string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Interface Class

  ```
  public interface SelectedValue {

  void onSelectedData(String string);
  ```

  }
- Set Value where you need to , 
  Above your activity class onCreate method()

  private SelectedValue mCallback;
- Override the onAttach

  ```
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  super.onAttach(activity);
  try {
      mCallback = (SelectedValue) activity;
  } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      Log.d("MyDialog", "Activity doesn't implement the ISelectedData interface");
  }
  ```

  }
- Implement

public class AyrintiliRapor extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener

- Override the method of your interface class

  ```
     public void onSelectedData(String value) {
      txt_tarih.setText("Hello"+value)}
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
/** The internal interface to extend */
public interface HelloInterface{
    String displayText(String prefix);
}

/** The internal class that uses the above interface */
public class HelloWorld{
    private HelloInterface myInterface;
    public void setHelloInterface(HelloInterface hi){
        myInterface=hi;
    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(hi.displayText("Hello"));
    }
}

/** Your main class */
public class myMainClass{
    private HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
    public void doIt(){
        hw.setHelloInterface(new HelloInterface{
            String displayText(String prefix){
                return prefix+" World!";
            }
        }
        hw.print(); // normally called by screenRedraw, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't quite get the part in the myMainClass Class where you call the setHelloInterface() method and pass in the interface obj.
Is the method displayText() is passed in the arguments as well?